# Random geometric graph connectivity

Tags: r, graph-theory

Given N random points uniformly distributed in the unit square, and a distance d, i can generate a matrix in the following format:

```
             E V1 V2
[1,] 0.5564821  1  2  
[2,] 0.3373116  1  3
[3,] 0.3973278  1  4
[4,] 0.6066518  1  5
[5,] 0.9603731  1  6
[6,] 0.3612895  1  7
# more rows...
```

Where E is the edge linking vertex V1 and V2. 
I've just started learning graph-theory, so i ask:

How can i determine if this random geometric graph is connected?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package statnet in R is very good.  It includes everything that is in the packages sna, network, and ergm.  Tutorial here: http://www.jstatsoft.org/v24/i09/paper

For your question regarding connectedness, you can use

```
library(statnet)
# generate an Erdos Renyi random graph g
# n vertices, m graphs, tprob is edge probability p
g <- rgraph(n=10, m=1, tprob=0.3) 
# components counts the number of components
components(rgraph(n=10, m=1, tprob=.5))
```

For your data above, just threshold the edges by throwing out all that are distance > d.  Keeping just the columns V1 and V2, you can do something like this:

```
V1 <- 1:10
V2 <- sample(10)
components(network(cbind(V1,V2))
```

The Penrose book http://books.google.com/books?id=M38e7nPGSCsC goes into detail about the theory.

Comment: Thanks, but i'm trying a 'raw' implementation! Can i just loop over V1 and V2 and count the visits at each node?

Comment: You might want to read the wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)#Algorithms